# Listview selects multiple items on tapping

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using list-view to show items in a Base-Adpater class. I inflate the view as

```
if (convertView == null || vi.findViewById(R.id.artist)== null)
            {
                View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list_lay, null);
            }
```

& set views click listener as:

```
vi.setOnClickListener(commonListen);
```

List view xml:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/table"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
 </ListView>
```

If I tap on more  than one item it selects all those items and performs the click listener operation of each view. I dont want this behaviour. I just want one item to be selected at one time.

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing is you are using `onClickListener`

You should use `onItemClickListener` whenever dealing with ListView.

Comment: I am inflating view through Base Adapter class in listview and doing functionality in adapter class. There is no item click listener on view as i am doing further functionality part on view's click